# Ajax response not bringing data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i'm making a web page where i take quiz question from my database and i show them in my page, im using ajax with php and MySQL, and i'm trying to do this:

```
    $.ajax({
    url:'../servicios/obtenerPregunta.php',
    type:'post',
    data:{

    },
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(response){
      var contenedorPreguntas = document.querySelector('.cont-pregunta-examen');
      contenedorPreguntas.innerHTML = response[0]['pregunta'];
    },
    error:function(request, error){
      alert(error);
    }
  });
```

here is my php:

```
<?php

require_once 'login.php';
$conexion = new mysqli($host_name,$user_name,$password,$data_base);

if($conexion->connect_error)die($conexion->error);

  $sentencia_sql = "CALL pa_obtener_preguntas";

  $resultado = $conexion -> query($sentencia_sql);

  if (!$resultado) die('Fallo la consulta a la BD, favor revisar la sentencia sql');

  $preguntas = array();

  while($pregunta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
  $preguntas[]=$pregunta;
    }

   echo json_encode($preguntas);

?>
```

I always use this method and works with other projects but in this case its not bringing nothing from my database, i mean, it doesn't shows any error or problem, its just that no data is brought from the database where i got the procedure and i tested and is working fine, my login.php is fine everything is working fine but i dont know why the **** this isn't working

Comment: Your best chance is to look up Network tab (devtools) and see the actual response.

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason could be because Ajax converts the response to object, not a regular array and you can't use `[0]` to get the first record of an object.

Use:

```
first = response[Object.keys(response)[0]]; //gets the first object
contenedorPreguntas.innerHTML = first['pregunta'];
```

### [Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/jx3zdtgw/)

Comment: under what circumstances would a browser change the content of a string sent by the server?

Answer (score 0):

You must set header to correct dataType in ajax request. So add

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

After

```
<?php
```